# Where to place Java classes for my JSP page in linux

Tags: java, linux, jsp

The statement `System.getProperty("java.class.path")` returns this path
`/usr/share/tomcat6/bin/bootstrap.jar`

I have a Java file named `user.java`. I am trying to use the `<jsp:useBean/>` tag. Where exactly should i place the Java file? Or should I first manually compile it and then place the `.class` file into a folder somewhere?

Comment: How `System.getProperty("java.class.path")` is related to your problem?

Comment: user class must be named User. Use uppercase as the first letter for classes. Also, put the User class in some package as mentioned by Thomas.

Comment: I gave that so that if CLASSPATH was relevant people could answer with that path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In web applications the classes are either in the application's `WEB-INF/classes` directory or in a jar in the `WEB-INF/lib` directory.

Note that you need to represent the package as well, so your class file needs to be in `WEB-INF/classes/mypackage/user.class` (provided the package is "mypackage").

Additionally, yes you need compiled class files not the source (except for JSPs which normally are compiled by the web server).

Comment: So every application has it's own WEB-INF folder? If that is true, should I manually create a folder named WEB-INF at the root of my application, since I am not using any IDE? Correct?

Comment: @Prometheus87 yes, each web application needs a `WEB-INF` folder that contains a `web.xml` file. Don't you already have that? If not does your application actually work? It would also be easier to use a build tool that can manage a big part of that boiler plate setup - look at tools like like Maven, Gradle etc.

Comment: my simple index.jsp page works fine. I haven't done the Bean part yet. but now i'll be using the Eclipse IDE.

Comment: @Prometheus87 So you don't have a .war file yet, right? Look up how those web archives are structured in order to put everthing in the correct place.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat has its own class paths.  See 
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html
Yes, Thomas is right. Use package and

```
<jsp:useBean class="myPackage.User"  ...
```